# Hospedagem e favicon erro 404

Tags: php, web-service, slim, postman

Possuo uma API desenvolvida com Slim 3. A API funcionava perfeitamente, testando com Postman ou pelo navegador, tudo funcionava perfeitamente.

Tive que alterar a hospedagem. Assim, subi a API para novo host e testei via navegador e funcionou. Quando testei pelo Postman ele me retornou o erro:

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

Voltei ao navegador e tentei novamente fazer a requisição, só que dessa vez com o console aberto. Percebi que juntamente com a requisição ao web service está indo uma requisição ao `favicon.ico` e como o arquivo não existe no host ele retorna um erro 404 juntamente com uma página de erro.

No navegador funciona, porém, ao testar via Postman ele me retorna o erro citado acima, o que não acontecia na antiga hospedagem.

Esse é o codigo da API:

```
$app = new app($container,[
    'settings' => [
        'displayErrorDetails' => true
    ]
]);

$app->group('/venda', function () use ($app) {
        $app->get('', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
                return 'teste';
        });  
});

$app->run();
```

E como ainda não passei o dominio para a nova hospedagem, utilizo esse link para acessar a API:

```
http://apiparsoni.rf.gd/v1/venda
```

Existe alguma maneira de mostrar ao navegador que se trata de uma API e impedir o de fazer essa requisição?

Comment: O fato do favicon não existir não parece ter relação com a resposta que obteve no Postman visto que este não faz a requisição ao favicon. Qual é o código do recurso que está requisitando e como fez essa requisição?

Comment: @PHPatrick Quando for editar uma pergunta, cuidado para não adicionar siglas e nomes próprios como trechos de código.

Comment: Fiz uma edição na pergunta e inclui mais informações do código do recurso e o link que faz a requisição.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Ué mas tudo que é relacionado a nome de funções, de APIs ou o próprio código em si cabe dentro do ``, ou não?

Comment: @PHPatrick Nome de funções sim; siglas no geral e nomes próprios fazem parte do texto e não demandam formatação especial.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Entendi beleza

Answer (score 1):

Dando uma pesquisada eu encontrei essa [issue](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/3344#issuecomment-449578285) no GitHub do Postman onde é mencionado que esse erro vem do seu servidor de hospedagem, normalmente originado em servidores de hospedagem free, onde desabilitam o uso de JavaScript para chamadas de API permitindo apenas por chamadas feitas por navegadores.

E pelo que me parece você esta hospedando no InfinityFree que é justamente o serviço de hospedagem citado na issue.

Verifique se no servidor onde esta hospedando tem alguma configuração para habilitar esse recurso, caso contrario terá que buscar outra alternativa.

Testei fazer a requisição por outros serviços online de teste de API e todos recebem o mesmo erro, confirmando que provavelmente este seja o problema realmente.

Caso queria testar segue 2 exemplos:

[ReqBin](https://reqbin.com/)

[ApiTester](https://apitester.com/)

Comment: Na verdade é quase isso. Sempre que é feito uma requisição nesta hospedagem é executada uma página interna deles que verifica alguns parâmetros da requisição com JS. Se estiver tudo ok, o usuário é movido para a página corretamente. No Postman não há um motor de execução para JS, por isso o erro é exibido.

Answer (score 1):

Isso é uma particularidade da hospedagem que você está utilizando.

Toda vez que alguém faz uma requisição neste servidor é verificado a existência do cookie `__test` - e possivelmente validado o valor dele (não temos como ter certeza). Quando o cookie não existe (ou inválido) o usuário é (internamente) direcionado para uma página da própria hospedagem. Não existe o redirecionamento real, apenas ao invés da requisição atingir a sua aplicação ela é processada pelo servidor, retornando uma página HTML com um código JS:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script>
        <script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f
            <d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("e783838a5007920e7955c7e2bd420274");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; location.href="http://apiparsoni.rf.gd/v1/venda?i=1";
            </script>
            <noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Que basicamente definirá o valor do cookie `__test` e moverá o usuário para uma nova URL com um parâmetro `i` na *query string* (possivelmente para evitar cache da própria página). Nesta nova requisição, como o cookie existirá e será válido, a requisição chegará à sua aplicação e você terá a resposta esperada.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o Postman não possui um motor de JavaScript interno, o código JavaScript da página não será executado e, por isso, o cookie não é criado e não é movido a página da sua aplicação. Inclusive, como utilizaram a tag `<noscript>`, é ela que é renderizada apresentando o erro descrito na pergunta.

Se você definir o valor de cookie manualmente com um valor válido a requisição funcionará normalmente no Postman:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Só não sei dizer por quanto tempo esse cookie permanecerá válido. Se considerar que ele define a validade como `expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37`, provavelmente você poderá utilizar o mesmo valor sem se preocupar.

Comment: Perfeito. É exatamente isso.. Mudei de host e tudo funcionou perfeitamente. Obrigado pela ajuda.